# Android:ListView not displaying items when power button locks the screen during AsyncTask

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, asynchronous, task

I have a Async Task that creates a HashMap to create a Adapter to populate ListView. I have a progress dialog that shows during doInBackground method.In onPostExecute() method, I dismiss the progress dialog and call a method that populates my listview with the list of items saved in doInBackground method.

This works fine. But I noticed something strange:

The issue I see is, if I lock the screen when the progress dialog is about to be dismissed (in onPostExecute), the listview does not display, even though it has non-empty items in it. I verified it in logcat messages and when I debugged.

Is there a possibility that a screen lock (I do this my pressing power button once) blocking UI thread? How can I resolve the issue and make sure ListView displays its items?

Code for onResume():

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(MyAdapter !=null){
        pull_listView.setAdapter(MyAdapter);//pull_listView is listview
        MyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//MyAdapter is the adapter

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This situation illustrates the downside of using AsyncTask to do background processing. In some cases, an IntentService may be a better choice, especially if you think the background work is going to take some time. An AsyncTask ties the background work to the current Activity, while an IntentService is completely decoupled.
The Android training class [Running in a Background Service](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html) shows you how to set up an IntentService, request work, and notify your Activity when the work is done. Passing data from the IntentService to the Activity is a bit more complicated, but there are options.

Comment: Agreed, but how would i display listview onResume(). I have a custom Base Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

`onStop()` will be called when your screen goes out as per the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). You could `override` `onStart()` or `onResume()` and put a check in there to see if your data has been populated. If not, populate. You may even want to overide 'onStop()' to save data if the screen goes out.

**Edit**

In this particular situation, I would think `onResume()` or `onStart()` would be fine but `onResume()` is usually the safest because it is guaranteed to get called before the `Activity` is shown as illistrated in the link I gave. What kiind of a check you want to use is up to you and depends on how you handle evrything. However, if your `AsyncTask` is an inner class of your `Activity` class the you could simply create a `boolean member variable`, say `boolean isDone=false;` change this to true in your `doInBackground()` or `onPostExecute()` then your `onResume()` knows the data Is loaded. If its false then you can try to get data again. Hope this makes sense and can help

Comment: In onStart() or onResume(), how do I check for listview populated or not? Is this a null check or Do I check the adapter size?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Try that and see if it works for you

Comment: I tried your suggestion in onResume(). It appears my adapter has data in it. I can see it has items loaded (MyAdapter.getCount() is > 0) and I call a method that populates listview. I still cannot see it populated. Do I reload the layout?

Comment: You might try calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `adapter`

Comment: I would debug your `getView()` method and see if the `Views` in your rows have values.Do you get any error at all or just a blank list?

Comment: Actually, my getView() is not even invoked in that circumstance. That explains why my listview does not show.

Comment: post your `getCount()` method or make sure it is returning the count of your `Array`

Comment: getCount() is displaying the correct number of the ArrayList. But the listview does not display.

Comment: You debugged and it never went to `getView()`? Without seeing more of your code I can't say what the problem is.

Comment: Well, the getView() does not get called onResume(), I am not sure why. Maybe I should re-create the ArrayList and re-create my custom base adapter.

Comment: Does it get called from `onCreate()`? If so, you can put that code in your `onResume()` then do it all from there since `onResume()` will always be called before your `Activity` starts

Comment: getView() gets called from onCreate(). I can't figure out how to rebuild the listview onResume() using my custom base adapter.